# Are duplicate accounts a problem?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-accounts

These 2 question were posted today from different accounts. The first just now and the second a couple of hours ago:

1. [Telling “other” Tasks to pause in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28539885/885318)
2. [Firing off multiple Tasks asynchronously and waiting for them to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28537250/885318)

The code in these answers make it seem as if it's the same person operating both accounts.

So, is this a problem, should something be done? Or is it just fine?

Comment: I raised a flag as this (^) post suggests.

Comment: It is only a problem if the accounts start voting for each other.

Comment: @Oded Seems reasonable, but only a moderator can know if that happens, right?

Comment: Yes. Moderators can see indications of vote fraud.

Comment: Consider that it is possible that these are colleagues working on the same codebase.

Comment: @Oded of course, I just wasn't aware if that's even an issue or what to do about it if it is.